# C# Infinite loop. How to apply loop control variable?

Tags: c#, while-loop

```
namespace QueenslandRevenue
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        

        Console.WriteLine("Number of contestants last year?>> ");
        int contestLast = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Number of contestatnts this year?>> ");
        int contestThis = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        Console.WriteLine(contestThis + contestLast);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Attempting an assignment. I know I need to add a loop control variable but Im not really sure what to do. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
        const int MAX = 30;
        const int MIN = 0;

        while (contestLast > MAX || contestLast < MIN || contestThis > MAX || contestThis < MIN)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid number of contestants");
            
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: read about logical operator &&

Comment: If the point is to ask for contestants until the number is valid, you need to assign the number within the loop, so that the number you check against with every iteration changes (therefore you have a chance of actualy exiting the loop).

Comment: Thank you. Forgive the poor formatting Im new to stack overflow and havent quiet grasped the formatting yet. I will read that.

Answer (score 4):

Inside the `static void Main(string[] args)` method, add a while loop which will keep running until the user enters valid inputs. when he does, you'll change the boolean variable `stop` to true so the execution will break the loop.

```js
int MAX = 30;
int MIN = 0;

bool stop = false;
while (!stop)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Number of contestants last year?>> ");
    int contestLast = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("Number of contestatnts this year?>> ");
    int contestThis = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


    Console.WriteLine(contestThis + contestLast);
    Console.ReadLine();    

    if (contestLast > MAX || contestLast < MIN || contestThis > MAX || contestThis < MIN)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid number of contestants");
        Console.ReadLine();            
    }
    else
    {
      stop = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I suggest *extracting a method* (we should not repeat ourselves):

```
 public static int ReadInteger(string title, 
                               int min = int.MinValue, 
                               int max = int.MaxValue) {
   int result;

   while (true) { // keep asking user ...
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
       Console.WriteLine(title);

     if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine), out result) 
       Console.WriteLine("Syntax error, please provide a valid integer.");
     else if (result < min || result > max) {
       Console.WriteLine($"The value {result} is out of range [{min}..{max}]");
     else
       return result; // ... until correct value has been provided
   }
 }
```

Then you can put

```
    int contestLast = ReadInteger("Number of contestants last year?>> ", 1, 30);
    int contestThis = ReadInteger("Number of contestants this year?>> ", 1, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user inputs `contestLast` correctly, but inputs `contestThis` incorrectly, it will just loop until the user specifies a correct value for `contestThis` instead of starting the whole process over.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int contestLast, contestThis;

    Console.Write("Number of contestants last year?>> ");

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out contestLast) || (contestLast < 0) || (contestLast > 30))
    {
        Console.Write("The specified value was either not a number or was not in range [0, 30], please try again>> ");
    }
    Console.Write("Number of contestatnts this year?>> ");

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out contestThis) || (contestThis < 0) || (contestThis > 30))
    {
        Console.Write("The specified value was either not a number or was not in range [0, 30], please try again>> ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(contestThis + contestLast);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can also write it as so if you need will need the loop for anything else:

```
private static int ReadNumber(string message, int min, int max)
{
    int result;

    Console.Write(message);

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) || (result < min) || (result > max))
    {
        Console.Write($"The specified value was either not a number or was not in range [{min}, {max}], please try again>> ");
    }
    return result;

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int contestLast = ReadNumber("Number of contestants last year?>> ", 0, 30);
    
    int contestThis = ReadNumber("Number of contestants this year?>> ", 0, 30);

    Console.WriteLine(contestThis + contestLast);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Main function you can try this:

```
int contestLast = 0;
int contestThis = 0;
const int MAX = 30;
const int MIN = 0;

do {
    Console.WriteLine("Number of contestants last year? ");
    contestLast = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Number of contestants this year? ");
    contestThis = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine(contestThis + contestLast);
    if (contestLast > MAX || contestLast < MIN || contestThis > MAX || contestThis < MIN)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter valid number of contestants");
} while (contestLast > MAX || contestLast < MIN || contestThis > MAX || contestThis < MIN);

Console.WriteLine("Finish");
```